# Could not build wheels for dependency-injector, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Tags: python, dependency-injection, pip, package, pyproject.toml

I'm installing "dependency-injector" package for my project. But it keeps showing error like below

```
(env) PS C:\Multi-Participants_Survey_Project-main-2\djangosurveybackend> pip install dependency-injector
Collecting dependency-injector
  Using cached dependency-injector-4.41.0.tar.gz (913 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting six<=1.16.0,>=1.7.0 (from dependency-injector)
  Using cached six-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: dependency-injector
  Building wheel for dependency-injector (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [54 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win32-cpython-312
      creating build\lib.win32-cpython-312\dependency_injector
      copying src\dependency_injector\errors.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\dependency_injector
      copying src\dependency_injector\resources.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\dependency_injector
      copying src\dependency_injector\schema.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\dependency_injector
      copying src\dependency_injector\wiring.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\dependency_injector
      copying src\dependency_injector\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\dependency_injector
      creating build\lib.win32-cpython-312\dependency_injector\ext
      copying src\dependency_injector\ext\aiohttp.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\dependency_injector\ext
      copying src\dependency_injector\ext\flask.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\dependency_injector\ext
      copying src\dependency_injector\ext\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\dependency_injector\ext
      copying src\dependency_injector\containers.pyi -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\dependency_injector
      copying src\dependency_injector\providers.pyi -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\dependency_injector
      copying src\dependency_injector\__init__.pyi -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\dependency_injector
      copying src\dependency_injector\py.typed -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\dependency_injector
      copying src\dependency_injector\containers.pxd -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\dependency_injector
      copying src\dependency_injector\providers.pxd -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\dependency_injector
      copying src\dependency_injector\ext\aiohttp.pyi -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\dependency_injector\ext
      copying src\dependency_injector\ext\flask.pyi -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\dependency_injector\ext
      copying src\dependency_injector\ext\__init__.pyi -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\dependency_injector\ext
      running build_ext
      building 'dependency_injector.containers' extension
      creating build\temp.win32-cpython-312
      creating build\temp.win32-cpython-312\Release
      creating build\temp.win32-cpython-312\Release\src
      creating build\temp.win32-cpython-312\Release\src\dependency_injector
      "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DCYTHON_CLINE_IN_TRACEBACK=0 -IC:\Multi-Participants_Survey_Project-main-2\djangosurveybackend\env\include -IC:\Users\truly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\include -IC:\Users\truly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Include "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\cppwinrt" /Tcsrc/dependency_injector/containers.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-cpython-312\Release\src/dependency_injector/containers.obj -O2
      containers.c
      src/dependency_injector/containers.c(33558): error C2039: 'curexc_traceback': is not a member of '_ts'
      C:\Users\truly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\include\cpython/pystate.h(115): note: see declaration of '_ts'
      src/dependency_injector/containers.c(33561): error C2039: 'curexc_traceback': is not a member of '_ts'
      C:\Users\truly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\include\cpython/pystate.h(115): note: see declaration of '_ts'
      src/dependency_injector/containers.c(34184): warning C4013: '_PyUnicode_Ready' undefined; assuming extern returning int
      src/dependency_injector/containers.c(36123): error C2039: 'gi_code': is not a member of 'PyGenObject'
      C:\Users\truly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\include\cpython/genobject.h(31): note: see declaration of 'PyGenObject'
      src/dependency_injector/containers.c(36123): error C2039: 'gi_code': is not a member of 'PyGenObject'
      C:\Users\truly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\include\cpython/genobject.h(31): note: see declaration of 'PyGenObject'
      src/dependency_injector/containers.c(37417): error C2039: 'ob_digit': is not a member of '_longobject'
      C:\Users\truly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\include\cpython/longintrepr.h(87): note: see declaration of '_longobject'
      src/dependency_injector/containers.c(38290): error C2039: 'ob_digit': is not a member of '_longobject'
      C:\Users\truly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\include\cpython/longintrepr.h(87): note: see declaration of '_longobject'
      src/dependency_injector/containers.c(38345): error C2039: 'ob_digit': is not a member of '_longobject'
      C:\Users\truly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\include\cpython/longintrepr.h(87): note: see declaration of '_longobject'
      src/dependency_injector/containers.c(38486): error C2039: 'ob_digit': is not a member of '_longobject'
      C:\Users\truly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\include\cpython/longintrepr.h(87): note: see declaration of '_longobject'
      src/dependency_injector/containers.c(38541): error C2039: 'ob_digit': is not a member of '_longobject'
      C:\Users\truly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\include\cpython/longintrepr.h(87): note: see declaration of '_longobject'
      src/dependency_injector/containers.c(39078): error C2039: 'ob_digit': is not a member of '_longobject'
      C:\Users\truly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\include\cpython/longintrepr.h(87): note: see declaration of '_longobject'
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.38.33130\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for dependency-injector
  Running setup.py clean for dependency-injector
Failed to build dependency-injector
ERROR: Could not build wheels for dependency-injector, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I don't know if it's related to my current Python version (3.12).Can anyone helps me with a solution, on how to fix this ?

I tried to download related packages by `pip install wheel`, `pip install pyproject-toml`, `pip install aiohttp` but still failed to download dependency-injector. I even change the download command to `pip3 install dependency-injector` and `pip install dependency-injector==4.41.0`, but none of them works

Answer (score 0):

`dependency-injector` currently supports Programming Languages Python 2.7, 3.5 - 3.11. [No support yet for Python 3.12](https://pypi.org/project/dependency-injector/#data).

You can install a supported python version and use virtual environments to manage projects like this that requires a specific python version.

For example, you can install Python 3.11 which is supported and then create a Python 3.11 virtual environment. Then you can `pip install dependency-injector` in that  environment.

Answer (score 0):

installing wheel 0.21.0
solved it for me
pip install wheel==0.21.0